# Reorder/Sidebar in Magento 1.7 shows invisible products - works in earlier versions

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have a plugin with a virtual product, that is set to `VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE`. It's a virtual product.

However, it is displayed in the widget "My orders" - but only in Magento 1.7. It works well in 1.6 and 1.5. I have tested in `Mage/Sales/Block/Reorder/Sidebar.php` in the `getItems()` method and it has indeed the correct `VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE`-state.

1. Has something changed between magento 1.6 to 1.7 in that regard? I can spot difference in the codebase, but not something that may be the cause of this behavior.
2. May this be a bug, as it only appears in 1.7?
3. Can I bypass this without touching the original codebase?

Comment: whats the plugin name ?

Comment: I developed it myself. I can share code or give access to a dev environment if you neeed ... Here are the links: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/327899/

Comment: Your question is vague.  It isn't clear if the item was in `getItems()` in both 1.6 and 1.7 or not.  Are you using the block template `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml` that corresponds with the above mentioned block. If you're using custom code or template, please post them.  Also post your desired behavior.

Comment: Sorry if I'm vague: I just installed three default magento installations with 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7. My code dors not touch sidebar.phtml. I just added a virtual product in my extension with visibilliy set to invisible (both). If you follow my link above, you can reach three testsystems with exactly the same code but different magento installations. The hidden product displays only in the "My Order" widget upon order details after buying and only 1.7! The desired behaviour is that the hidden product is not visible there, just like in 1.5 and 1.6. Which part of the code should I post?

Comment: I have checked again: The item does not reach the `getItems()` method of `Sidebar.php` in 1.6 or prior, but it does in 1.7.

Comment: i have installed 1.6 and ill tell you why this happen but could you tell whats the exact scenario that you trying ( create virtual in 1.6 and 1.7 then do an order and then you the virtual item will appear in 1.6 and not in 1.7 ) is this right ??

Comment: Vice versa. The element is set to invisible and it (correctly) does not appear in 1.6, but in 1.7. You can easily see by visiting `livecosmopolit.com/magento17` or `livecosmopolit.com/magento16` and buy something as `Mail: kontakt@elefunds.de / PW: elefunds` and make sure to check the donation.

You'll notice that the "My orders" Widget displays the invisible virtual product, linking to a 404 in 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. I'm not sure if this is bug ( but as the functionality wise this should be bug ).

So the difference between 1.6 ( and older version ) / and 1.7 is:

The Model

> Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Has This method

```
protected function _getItemsRandomCollection($limit, $nonChildrenOnly = false){  

        $(...)->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds()) // This is Visibility check ( its fine ) 
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $product = $productsCollection->getItemById($item->getProductId());
                if ($product) {
                    $item->setProduct($product); // Set Object Data ( 'product' ) if it exists 
                }
            }

}
```

So In the previous code the last ordered item collection has property called 'product' that hold the product object if its returned and its not set if its not returned.

The above code is fine and works no issues in it.

In Model

> Mage_Sales_Block_Reorder_Sidebar

The getItems Method is :

```
/**
 * Get list of last ordered products
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getItems()
{
    $items = array();
    $order = $this->getLastOrder();
    $limit = 5;

    if ($order) {
        $website = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        foreach ($order->getParentItemsRandomCollection($limit) as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct() && in_array($website, $item->getProduct()->getWebsiteIds())) {
                $items[] = $item;
            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

=================================================================================
**In Magento 1.6 and prior versions**

When you call *$item->getProduct();* in sidebar block,

it will return the object property ( Mage_Catalog_Model_Product - product instance - ) that has been set in the method above ( _getItemsRandomCollection() )

OR it will return NULL if not set.

So if it returns Product object the item will be shown in the sidebar block and if not the return array will not contain that *Virtual Item*

=================================================================================
**In Magento 1.7**

When you call *$item->getProduct();* in sidebar block,

===>> *This method is implemented in the model*

> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item

When you call the method it will be executed from the model ( it won't lookup for object property ).

So if you take a look at the method implementation

```
/**
 * Retrieve product
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    if (!$this->getData('product')) { // If no object attribute set with name ('product')
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId()); // it will always return product instance with that product id.
        $this->setProduct($product); // set it to the current sidebar item
    }

    return $this->getData('product'); // return the object property 'product'
}
```

So In the case if the method ( _getItemsRandomCollection() ) didn't set the object property 'product' because its not visible or something ( This method will assign it by product ID directly without checking for visibility or anything else.

**Yes I consider this a bug and it need to be fixed**

*That was the answer for the reason why*

=================================================================================

**The solution is pretty simple**

1.Create custom module.

2.Extend/Rewrite the Model.

> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item

3.Override the method and ( Comment the code Block) or add The visibility check in the method.

Solution 1 ( comment the code block that set the item product ).

```
/**
 * Retrieve product
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    /** comment from here 
    *if (!$this->getData('product')) {
    *    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
    *    $this->setProduct($product);
    *}
    * Till here.
    */
    return $this->getData('product');
}
```

**OR**

Solution 2 : Add the visibility check to the method as below.

```
/**
 * Retrieve product
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    if (!$this->getData('product')) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
        if(!$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) // add visibility check here
        {
             $this->setProduct($product);
        }
    }

    return $this->getData('product');
}
```

I have spent some time doing this :) hope it helps you !

Comment: Okay, this is by far the greatest answer I've ever got on stackoverflow. I have myself spend lots of time here, but was a little limited, since I'm new to magento. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe it's worth, filling a bug report ... I'll try to get some feedback on this, thx.